# Create Single Flash app for AIR and Flash Player on Android

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

We are planning to create a P2P app for android platform and we have choosen Adobe RTMFP and Flash for this. 
Since both Flash Player and AIR are supported by limited Android versions we must make an flash app that can run in android versions.

**Finally, the question is how can we Create a single Flash app that will be supported in all android devices either via Flash player or via AIR**

Comment: Likely a waste of time.  Adobe is abandoning flash on android in the future.  As of the moment I'm pretty sure there will no longer be any updates.

Comment: I would not say it is a waste of time. The Flash for android will be for sure dropped (if not already), but native AIR apps have better and better performance. Also you can use captive runtime which saves your user for the need of installing Adobe AIR. + You can have same app distributed on iOS and BB. So with limited resources I would say that AIR/AS3 is the best option so far.

Comment: @chillax Adobe isn't abandoning Flash; just the Flash Player for Android; which is a small part of the "Flash" ecosystem.  he browser based Flash Player for Android is already long gone [unless you're in the UK where the BBC put pressure on Adobe to keep it in the app store].  If BabbarTushar wants to build a Native Application; then he can use Adobe AIR to build an APK for deployment to Android.  I would expect issues on any device that is Android 2.1 or earlier.  I would expect the APK to work fine on current devices.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com You can't install AIR apps on 2.1 or earlier anyway, even with Captive Runtime if I remember correctly. And with 40% of Android devices running 4.0+ and 90% running 2.3+, you don't really need to worry about those devices anyway (unless you know for sure your target market utilizes those devices, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems in creating such app. Just create browser version(be careful not to use browser features like `JS` via `ExternalInterface`), and then load it either in browser or in simple AIR wrapper with single `SWFLoader`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Since Air is not supported in Android < 4.0x,  How can i make this app compatible for android 2.2 - 4.0 . So that the app can run in both Flash player and Air supporting android device.

Comment: You shall see what it the flash player version for old android's browser and develop your app for it. In old anroids you will display it in browser.  In latest androids you can load same app inside air app.